# What is the meaning of QoS2 in MQTT

Tags: mqtt

In MQTT I have still problems to understand QoS2.
The 4-way handshake is:

1. message is sent from a sender to the receiver
2. Receiver answers with PUBREC
3. Sender answers with PUBLREL
4. Receiver answers with PUBCOMP

But what happens, when receiver gets message in the first step, but the PUBREC message gets lost?

Then the sender must retry to send the message.
In this situation, however, we already have sent the message twice what is what we want to avoid.

So how can we say, that QoS2 guarantees, that a message is sent exactly once?
What important feature I'm still missing?

Comment: does it mean, that a message can be sent multiple times, but with the same package-identifier? 
So QoS2 only prevents the reuse of a packet identifier as long as PUBCOMP has not been received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing this part from [the spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901237):

> Until [the receiver] has received the corresponding `PUBREL` packet, the receiver MUST acknowledge any subsequent `PUBLISH` packet with the same Packet Identifier by sending a `PUBREC`. It MUST NOT cause duplicate messages to be delivered to any onward recipients in this case [MQTT-4.3.3-10].

So...the receiver essentially ignores the duplicate `PUBLISH` packets.

Comment: OK, that was the missing point. Now I understand. Some online video tutorials don't really make this clear.